# Why is getdate(0) returning 1 as the hour?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using the getdate function, and I'm intending to use it to parse a time interval, in seconds, into days, minutes, hours, etc. However, I'm surprised that `getdate(0)['hours']` is 1. What's going on here?

FWIW, the complete output I get is:

```
Array
(
    [seconds] => 0
    [minutes] => 0
    [hours] => 1
    [mday] => 1
    [wday] => 4
    [mon] => 1
    [year] => 1970
    [yday] => 0
    [weekday] => Thursday
    [month] => January
    [0] => 0
)
```

Comment: Your timezone, I'm guessing.

Comment: I just got '0' on the command line...

Comment: How can I stop it from using a timezone then? I was testing this from http://ideone.com/.

Answer (score 5):

`January 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT` was `01:00` in BST (British Standard Time). Your server presumably has that time zone set.

See [this Wolfram Alpha query.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=January%201,%201970,%20GMT%20in%20UK%20Time)

Use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to change the time zone, or use the new [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class that is completely timezone aware.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are living in the UK.

PHP is configured to use the local timezone of your country. This results in a time of 1:00: GMT + 1 hour for the Daylight Savings.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- Substract one hour from the timestamp you're using
- Configure your script to use GMT. Use the function @pekka mentioned to do this.

I suggest the first solution; your script might need to pretty print individual times, along with the intervals, which you want to have converted to your local timezone.